# ¿Alguien sabe como resolver el problema de dependencias para picom?

Tags: linux, kali-linux

Tengo un problema, al tratar de instalar el programa picom:

```
sudo apt-get install picom
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede 
significar que 
usted pidió en una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se 
han sacado un <<Incoming>>
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

Los siguiente paquetes tiene dependencias incumplidas:
picom: Depende: libx11-xcb1 (>=2:1.8.7) pero 2:1.8.4-2+deb12u2 va a ser instalado
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.
```

Espero una respuesta, gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Este sitio es sobre programacion, no instalcion de sistemas operativos... vas a tener mas suerte en un sitio de linux...

Comment: El error indica un problema con las versiones de una librería. Necesitas una versión pero solo está disponible una inferior. Hay varias soluciones: busca el paquete de de la librería en la versión correcta, lo instalas y luego instalas picom; busca una versión de picom más antigua y la instalas (sin usar apt-get); actualizas la distro(creo que tienes un debían 12); activa los paquetes contrib y non-free en tu apt-get; cambia s una distribución anterior; utiliza un docker con picom...

Comment: hacer un `sudo apt update`  podr'ia ayudar.